# How do I get one record if it has the same multiple by clicking smart field and shows on browser?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Hello OpenEdge/Progress 4GL!!!

I think I need an idea from you. I have created a smart viewer window and added smart fields on it. Whenever I click on then it takes a data directly from db every time.

But the concern here is i could have same multiple data and should see only one from them.

Let me share what i set it up

```
/* Under Dynamic Lookup - Smart Fields */
/* Base query string */
FOR EACH part NO-LOCK INDEXED-REPOSITION
Key Field: Part_obj
Displayed field: part_id
Fieldlabel: PARTS LIST
Browse title: Lookup


/* This is a setup that we can do in smart field instance properties*/
```

As you see above base query string is FOR EACH in dynamic look up so that its shows all the data even if it is found the same multiple data

Could you please help me to filter duplicates if its possible in dynamic look up?

Comment: I can't simulate your data accurately, try looking into `FIRST-OF` (which requires `BREAK BY` in your for each). It might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is, if the data is not unique, how will you know you are displaying the correct record? If there are multiple records that satisfy the query and there shouldn't be, then you either need to clean up the data, or add some criteria to ensure uniqueness. 
One way to do this would be to add a GUID or some other unique key to the table and use that to display the correct record, alternatively you can use the ROWID () of the record.